# how to handle angular routing in existing .net mvc project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, angular-routing

I am working with existing MVC5 application, here i have to apply Angular routing to make it as SPA and am able to apply that. But i got some issues while integrating angular routing with mvc application. on any postback the application goes back to the MVC routing again and if i refresh the page again it's goes into mvc. Please suggest how to stop MVC routing when we intend to use angular routing in a MVC application?

For ex : I have a set of scaffold pages for a table to perform CRUD operations. To apply Angular routing it seems the Layout of the views to be made null. So on a save button click in Create or Edit, the data gets saved but because of its postback, the routing changes from angular to mvc and the page gets displayed with out a layout which means it is going to mvc routing. Please suggest